# How can I stop the text from jumping in this enlarged bootstrap material design select box?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, bootstrap-material-design

I have [a fiddle for this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/ypcrumble/t49etfx7/1/)  that I can't seem to figure out.

I'm trying to increase the size of a select box in [bootstrap material design](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/). It's using the [selectize plugin](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design#selectizejs).

Here's the LESS I'm using:

```
.selectize-control.single,
.selectize-control.multi {
  .selectize-input, .selectize-input.input-active {
    font-size: 40px;
    input {
      font-size: 40px;
    }   
  }
}
```

Everything in the fiddle works, except for one scenario. If I choose one option, then try to choose a second option, the first choice's text jumps down a little so it's right on top of the line below it. How can I stop this jump from happening?

Comment: The input field is switching between position:relative and absolute when you click it. You could force it to always use one or the other.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer that solves your issue...

Answer (score 1):

You probably sorted that one out, but as per suggestion of @Hywel Ress and use of `!important`, you can pin your `input` once and for all:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/t49etfx7/2/)

```
input[type="text"] {
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me.

```
.selectize-control.single,
 .selectize-control.multi {
 .selectize-input,
 .selectize-input.input-active {
  font-size: 40px;
       height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    white-space: nowrap;
   input {
   font-size: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
    }
  }
```